# Trying to shift the Validation from Controller to Request Class in Laravel 5.2.15

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**I have a very simple Rule method in request class like below.**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'Subject'           => 'required|max:50',
        'Description'       => 'required|max:500',
        'DepartmentID'      => 'required|integer|min:1',
        'PriorityID'        => 'required|integer|min:1'
    ];
}
```

**Inside Controller Action method, below is the code.**

```
private function SaveChanges(\App\Http\Requests\TicketRequest $request) {

    $v = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    ]);

    $DepartmentAdmins = $this->getDepartmentAdmins();

    //Check if department admin missing then no need to add the record
    if($DepartmentAdmins == null || count($DepartmentAdmins) == 0) {
        $v->errors()->add('MissingAdmins', 'Department admin missing.');
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($v->errors());
    }
}
```

**Question:**

As we can see in the `rule` method there are 4 form fields. Is there any way to shift the check for Department Admin existence from Controller Action method to `request` class?

Comment: Your question is little bit confusing but if you want the rules to be like
`$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
                'body' => 'required',
  ]);`

And the check for other requirements.

Comment: What does getDepartmentAdmins() do?

Comment: Inside Controller Action method, I am searching for Users for a Department. So, if no user found then no need to save the record and impose validation.

Comment: you can easily do it by route model binding. 
Take a look at this: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/18

Comment: I would argue this is more middleware than validation - why let someone submit something to tell them they're not allowed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laravel's `Request` has `after` hook that can be run after normal validation completes. This is how you can use it in your case:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use App\Models\Property;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class SomeRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Get the validator instance for the request.
     *
     * @return Validator
     */
    protected function getValidatorInstance()
    {
        $instance = parent::getValidatorInstance();
        $instance->after(function ($validator) {
            $this->validateDepartmentAdmins($validator);
        });

        return $instance;
    }

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'Subject'           => 'required|max:50',
            'Description'       => 'required|max:500',
            'DepartmentID'      => 'required|integer|min:1',
            'PriorityID'        => 'required|integer|min:1'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param Validator $validator
     */
    public function validateDepartmentAdmins(Validator $validator)
    {
        $DepartmentAdmins = $this->getDepartmentAdmins();

        //Check if department admin missing then no need to add the record
        if($DepartmentAdmins == null || count($DepartmentAdmins) == 0) {
            $validator->errors()->add('MissingAdmins', 'Department admin missing.');
        }
}
```

That way you won't have to do any validation in your SaveChanges controller method.

This code is used in Laravel 5.1, but I believe it will work the same in 5.2.

Comment: You can do any custom validation in Request methods called in `after` hook. Isn't that what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: I think, your suggestion is off-topic. Kindly recheck my question.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Does it make more sense to you now?

Comment: Error occurred in above code `Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Requests\CountryRequest::CheckCountryExists() must be an instance of App\Http\Requests\Validator, instance of Illuminate\Validation\Validator given`

Comment: That should be `$validator` - I just copied from your code. Also I omitted use clauses - now added them back - you used wrong `Validator` class. Updated my answer

Comment: @Helper You can always use a `Closure` instead of the `array`.  This is the more appropriate answer IMO.

Comment: @ash, Yes, we could use closure there as well, but we actually need `Validator` instance that is passed from the hook, so we would need to also pass it to our custom method. In my opinion simple array looks cleaner in this case

Comment: @IvanYarych you can send the `$validator` instance to the closure with `use ($v)`

Answer (score 1):

The Form Request Class basically has two methods. "authorize" and "rules". the best way to shift the check for Department Admin existense is to add your own custom validator(for example named "adminCountValidator") and implement your logic for checking the number of administrators there. Then use yoir newly defined validator in "rules" method like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'Subject'           => 'required|max:50',
        'Description'       => 'required|max:500',
        'DepartmentID'      => 'required|integer|min:1|adminCountValidator',
        'PriorityID'        => 'required|integer|min:1'
    ];
}
```

if you define a custome validation rule, you can also define the associated error message and your controller action will be much more cleaner. here is the link for defining your own custom validator 
[custom-validation-rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules)

here is a sample code for adding a custom validator within a service provider

```
    class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('adminCountValidator', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            /*
           implement your getDepartmentAdmins() 
           function here and return true or false
            */
            });
    }
```

Comment: Can you show code about `adminCountValidatorin` validation?

Comment: @Helper I Edit my answer and inserted a sample code for defining your custom validator.

Comment: This solution is good when you plan to use your validator in different places. But you only need to use it single request - in my opinion it is better to use the hook as in my answer